# ember-cli how to make brocolli ignore certain files' changes

Tags: vim, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using ember-cli v0.0.47 and I would like to be able to make brocolli ignore some files' changes when it triggers a build.

I'm using vim as authoring tool and I have it configured to save all my open files whenever the editor looses focus (this includes swap and undo files). This has the unfortunate side effect of causing a lot of unnecessary rebuilds of my ember-cli project because brocolli detects that the files have been changed and proceeds to rebuild.

As such I'd like to be able to somehow tell brocolli not to trigger a rebuild of the project when some files have been changed. Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a way to exclude files from Broccoli, but generally this is indeed a problem and it helps to write vim's temporary files elsewhere to prevent frequent rebuilds, so in your `.vimrc`:

```
set backupdir=~/.vim/backup//
set directory=~/.vim/swp//
```

You have to create the directories manually as well.

The extra slash is needed so it preserves the file structure within that directory. From `:help directory` in vim:

```
    - For Unix and Win32, if a directory ends in two path separators "//"
      or "\\", the swap file name will be built from the complete path to
      the file with all path separators substituted to percent '%' signs.
      This will ensure file name uniqueness in the preserve directory.
      On Win32, when a separating comma is following, you must use "//",
      since "\\" will include the comma in the file name.
```